# Substring a Word from a Multiline Textboxes

Tags: vb.net

I want to do the following thing: if I have a Textbox1.Lines:

```
2
5
15
21
45
```

and I want to for example get the number left 15 and get the number right 15.
Output: Textbox2.Lines `15 21`

```
5 15
```

How should I do this? example for the number 2 want substring `2 5`

Module Module1

```
Public Function FirstWords(input As String,
                           count As Integer) As String
    Dim words = count
    For i As Integer = 0 To input.Length - 1
        ' Decrement word count when we reach a space.
        If input(i) = " " Then
            words -= 1
        End If
        ' When no words remaining, return a substring to this point.
        If words = 0 Then
            Return input.Substring(0, i)
        End If
    Next
    Return ""
End Function
```

how should i do this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate them into an array of strings with the `Split` function, like in this example:

```
    Dim input as String = "2 5 15 21 45"

    Dim numbers as String() = input.Split(" ")

    For Each s as String In numbers
        Console.WriteLine(s)
    Next
```

You just have to figure out how to extract the numbers you want from the lot. Have fun!

Comment: I understood this theoretically somewhat. how can i get the numbers next to it? left and right as shown above.

Comment: what does S represent? how do I replace S with my value?

Comment: @AlexAlex It's part of the scope of the `For Each` loop, and represent one of the strings in the `numbers` array. In the first iteration of the loop, it represents the first item in the array, then the next one, etc. until every item has been processed.